# Jinja escapes HTML in set block

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I'm using a Jinja `{% set %}` block to define a user link that I want to render to the page later. However, when I render the variable all the HTML is escaped so it show the HTML instead of the link.

```
{% set user_link %}
    <a href="url_for('main.user', username=post.author.username)">
        {{ post.author.username }}
    </a>
{% endset %}
```

View source shows:

```
&lt;a href=&#34;/user/exampleuser&#34;&gt;
    exampleuser
&lt;/a&gt;
```

Which displays the literal HTML on the page:

```
<a href="/user/exampleuser"> exampleuser </a>
```

How can I render the link defined in the `set` block instead of the raw HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask's Jinja environment will autoescape rendered variables unless they are marked safe. `set` does not mark its contents as safe, since it can't know what you intend to use it for.

You can mark the `set` block safe when you define it. (This requires Jinja >= 2.10.)

```
{% set user_link|safe %}
    ...
{% endset %}
```

Or you can mark the variable it produces safe when you render it.

```
{{ user_link|safe }}
```

Only one is required. Using both is redundant but won't break anything.

Answer (score 0):

Note that there:

`href="{{ url_for('main.user', username=post.author.username) }}"`

```
{% set user_link %}
    <a href="{{ url_for('main.user', username=post.author.username) }}">
        {{ post.author.username }}
    </a>
{% endset %}
```